# assign value to external variable inside Linux awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting, sh

I need your helps about assigning value to external variable inside awk command.Please check the following script

```
interfaceName=$1
exitStatus=0

ip -o link show | awk '{ if($2=="'$interfaceName'") $exitStatus=1}'

if(exitStatus==0) then
  exit 0

else 
  exit 1
fi
```

The script takes network interface name as argument then check the available interfaces which match with the taken. if find matched interface it, exits with  1 else with 0.The problem is that i cannot change the external variable **exitStatus** inside awk in the following line

```
awk '{ if($2=="'$interfaceName'") $exitStatus=1}'
```

How to assign value to it in awk ?

Comment: You can't. You gotta `print` the value and catch it to a variable, like: `foo=$(awk 'BEGIN{print "foo"}') ; echo $foo` (and mind the quotes in the shell side).

Comment: I see,thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make awk return an exit status to the shell:

```
ip -o link show | awk '{ if($2=="'$interfaceName'") exit 1}'

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    # TODO
```